# couldn't understand this sed command. can anyone explain it?

Tags: bash, awk, sed

```
sed -i 's/^  /0/' inputfile
```

and also this:

```
awk '{if (previoustime>$1)
            {{system("getDate")}{system("printTimestamp")}{print ""}}
            {previoustime=$1}
            {print $0}
    }' inputfile
```

In the above script, **getDate** will update timestamp in a temporary file to the next day and **printTimestamp** will print the following line with the updated timestamp in another file:

```
00:00:01 (lmgrd) TIMESTAMP <Date>
```

1. In the first script, what does the two spaces after 'tux' mean?
2. In the second script, as $1 means the first column and here, the 1st column in the input file is a time. How can it compare two times?

The following is the input file format:

```
21:49:32 (lmgrd) MLM using TCP-port 37034
21:51:08 (MLM) TCP_NODELAY NOT enabled
 3:49:30 (lmgrd) TIMESTAMP 5/18/2014
 3:54:33 (MLM) TIMESTAMP 5/18/2014
 9:49:30 (lmgrd) TIMESTAMP 5/18/2014
 9:59:37 (MLM) TIMESTAMP 5/18/2014

getMonthDays () {
    MAX=31
    if [ $1 -eq 2 ]; then
            MAX=29
    fi
    cal $1 $2 | grep $MAX >> /dev/null
    printf $((MAX-$?))
}

getDate () {
    if [ -f OUTPUTDATE.tmp ]; then
            IN=$(cat OUTPUTDATE.tmp)

            MONTH=$(echo $IN | cut -d \/ -f 1)
            DAY=$(echo $IN | cut -d \/ -f 2)
            YEAR=$(echo $IN | cut -d \/ -f 3)

            MDAYS=$(getMonthDays $MONTH $YEAR)
            (((DAY+=1)>MDAYS)) && ((DAY=1)) && (((MONTH+=1)>12)) && ((MONTH=1)) && ((YEAR+=1))

            OUTPUTDATE="$MONTH/$DAY/$YEAR"
            echo $OUTPUTDATE > OUTPUTDATE.tmp
    fi
}

printTimestamp () {
    if [ -f OUTPUTDATE.tmp ]; then
            OUTPUTDATE=$(cat OUTPUTDATE.tmp)
            printf %s "00:00:01 (lmgrd) TIMESTAMP "$OUTPUTDATE
    fi
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code `getDate` and `printTimestamp`?

Comment: The awk command is someone trying to use awk as a shell which is it NOT appropriate for. Their syntax is ridiculously wrong which is a huge clue that they have no idea what they're doing. All of that shell and sed stuff could have been done trivially in one small, simple awk script. If you post another question with sample input and expected output and tag it with `awk`, someone will show you how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first command finds any instances of two spaces at the start (`^`) of a line, and replaces them (`s//`) with a `0`.

The `-i` means that the file that `sed` is operating on gets modified *in place*. Without this, the modified version would get written to the console (stdout), but without changing the original file.

Your second command is updating the timestamp, yes. It's able to compare two times *because* the `sed` command replaced trailing spaces with a `0`. Once that's been done, string comparison tells you whether one time is after another, just using alphanumeric ordering. Without the `sed` command, you would get strange results: `3:00:00` would come after `21:00:00` because `3` comes after `2`.

Comment: oookk!! then I guess it is trying to make the timestamp in a specific format like " 4:23:30" to "04:23:30" ..yep 1st is solved. any ideas on the 2nd script?

Comment: @JeevanPatnaik I've edited my answer to explain the second bit.

Answer (score 1):

sed script replaces the 2 spaces at the start of line (represented by `^`) by 0

Answer (score 1):

The search regex is two spaces at the start of the line.
The replace term is the digit 0.
The `-i` option means "in place": the result of the edit is written back over onto the source file (instead of to stdout).